# What will happen to the sanctions against Russia if it succeeds in conquering Ukraine?

Tags: international-relations, russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, sanctions

I am wondering what will happen to all the sanctions against Russia if it succeeds in conquering Ukraine. As far as I understand it, the purpose of the sanctions against Russia, at this point in time, are meant to persuade Putin not to complete his conquest of Ukraine and to immediately redraw all his military forces from Ukraine as soon as possible.

So, if he succeeds in conquering all of Ukraine, then the intended goal of the sanctions will have failed, and as far as I can see it, there will be little reason for the sanctions to be continued beyond the day in which Putin declares that his mission in Ukraine has been completed.

What will happen to the sanctions against Russia if it succeeds in conquering Ukraine?